# What is PROPFIND request

Tags: propfind

In the postman, there are multiple request types and I see **PROPFIND** but do not actually know what are its aspects and usage, just curious if it is useful for future use anyone can explain it in simple terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PROPFIND — used to retrieve properties, stored as XML, from a web resource. It is also overloaded to allow one to retrieve the collection structure (a.k.a. directory hierarchy) of a remote system.

Answer (score 3):

PROPFIND is a WebDAV request used with HTTP servers that enable WebDAV. HTTP was developed with requests GET, PUT, POST, PATCH, and DELETE. WebDAV, which stands for Web Distributed Authoring and Versioning, extends the requests to add MKCOL, LOCK, UNLOCK, COPY, MOVE, PROPFIND, and PROPATCH. PROPFIND (Property Find) is a complex WebDAV request that allows clients to request from a WebDAV enabled server an XML response containing a listing of all the items in the collection specified in the request matching the properties specified in the request. Thus, to oversimplify, a client (you on your computer) may want to retrieve all html files on a server site matching a regular expression, and having version numbers after a given version number, and authored by user JimBrokaw, and approved by Director AliceFaye. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) for a more thorough description.